# Could you simplify the highlighted parts , please

Tags: word-meaning

> Houston's economy has a broad industrial base in energy, manufacturing, aeronautics, and transportation. It is also leading in health care sectors and building oilfield equipment; only New York City is home to more **Fortune 500** headquarters.The Port of Houston ranks first in the United States in international ** waterborne tonnage handled** and second in **total cargo tonnage handled**. The city has a population from various ethnic and religious backgrounds and a large and growing international community. It is home to many cultural institutions and exhibits, which attract more than 7 million visitors a year to the Museum District. Houston has an active visual and performing arts scene in the Theater District and offers **year-round resident companies in all major performing arts**.

I have a great deal of difficulty, understanding the highlighted parts.

1. Wondering what the word **Fortune** here means.
2. **waterborne tonnage handled** and ** total cargo tonnage handled** ?
3. ** year-round resident companies in all major performing arts**. ?

A million thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Fortune 500 is the name of a list compiled by *Fortune* magazine:

> The Fortune 500 is an annual list compiled and published by Fortune magazine that ranks the top 500 U.S. closely held and public corporations as ranked by their gross revenue

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_500)

Waterborne tonnage is the amount of goods (in tons) brought in or taken out by ship. *Waterborne* means 'conveyed by or travelling on water'. Total cargo tonnage is the amount of goods brought in or taken out by all methods - land, sea and air.

'Year round resident companies' - a group of theatre performers is called a *company*. These often travel around to various theatres. A 'year round resident company' is a company that performs at the same theatre all year rather than touring.